# Selecting groups of records using FIRST.var

Tags: sas

My dataset is:

```
ID     AGE

1      65
1      66
1      67
1      68
1      69
1      70
1      71
2      70
2      71
2      72
3      68
3      69
3      70

 [...]
```

My (basic) question is: which is the most direct way for obtaining a dataset with ID records starting with `65 <= AGE <= 68`? (in the above example I would like to get the first 7 rows and the last three). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data input_dataset;
input ID     AGE;
cards;
1      65
1      66
1      67
1      68
1      69
1      70
1      71
2      70
2      71
2      72
;
run;

proc sort data=input_dataset out=sorted;
by ID;
run;

data work.first_age65to68;
  set sorted;
  retain keepit 0;
  by ID;
  if first.ID then do;
      if AGE ge 65 and AGE le 68 then keepit=1;
      else keepit=0;
  end;
  if keepit;
  drop keepit;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to have another method...

```
proc sql;
  delete from input_dataset I where not exists 
    (select 1 from input_dataset D where I.id=D.id having 65 le min(age) le 68);
quit;
```

If you want to create a new dataset, the same basic query would work as part of a SELECT, reversing the NOT.